# WFR and Rollup Summary Field - RollUp has 20+ decimal places

Tags: workflow, roll-up-summary, multi-currency

In an org with multi currency enabled.

1. Parent Object ISO Code set to USD
2. Child field Amount = USD295.00
3. Corporate Currency is set to EUR and the Conversion Rate is set to 1,0000

Debug output of Amount field (on child) using the following debug (Just to show that there are no other decimal places in the DB not being shown on the UI):

```
ChargentOrders__Transaction__c tran = [Select ChargentOrders__Amount__c  From ChargentOrders__Transaction__c Where ID = 'a2c20000000hAXm'];
Decimal orig = tran.ChargentOrders__Amount__c;
system.debug(orig);

orig = orig.setScale(23);
system.debug(orig);
```

The output is below:

[image]

However when the WFR runs that evaluates if the Roll-Up Summary field (transaction_total) on the parent is Equal to another field (Total) on the parent this is the output

[image]

For some reason the rollup is changing the value to something else. The rollup is in USD, the ISO Code on the Parent is USD.

Any ideas why the Roll-Up Summary is modifying the value yet Aggregate Querys using convert currency, not using convert currency, and just regular queries mentioned above all return 295.00?

Basically, every query I make shows a result of $295.00 with no additional decimal places. The only place where this weird number is being displayed is a WFR that evaluates if the Roll-Up Summary Field is = the Amount field. And the WFR is not evaluating to true because the value of 294.999999...128 is < the value of $295.00

**Added**

Per comments below I also explicitly debugged the value of the Rollup summary field (thought it was clear with the original debug of the fields being rolled up)

Code:

```
ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c ord = [Select ChargentOrders__transaction_total__c From ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c Where ID = 'a2Z200000021zF3'];
system.debug(ord.ChargentOrders__Transaction_total__c);
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Normally your questions are very clear, but I'm having a bit of a hard time following this one. The last two paragraphs specifically left me more confused. In terms of the setup, are you just rolling up one detail with `295`, and it sums to `294.999...`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Sorry for the confusion. Yes, it is rolling up One (1) transaction and the UI and query for the rollup field show 250.00 yet the WFR Debug shows 249.999999999999999999999128. I tried to clear it up. Basically a WFR is evaluating the equality of two fields. One being a RUS field and only in the WFR does it show 249.9999...128

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Updated question, hopefully it is clearer as I see where I introduced the confusion

Comment: Eric -- your code references field `ChargentOrders__Amount__c` but the workflow debug references two different fields, neither being `ChargentOrders__Amount__c`

Comment: @cropredy - Right, The Amount field referenced in my code is on the Child object and is what is being rolled up to the Transaction Total on the parent. I was trying to show that the field being rolled up does not contain any decimal places that are not shown in the UI that could affect the rollup

Comment: related - http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000170763

Comment: @cropredy - Not really. That is exactly why I have the code at the beginning of my question to show that there is NO additional values stored in the database. it is all 000000000000000 and I have confirmed that only 295.00 is entered (I reentered it manually before the debug). I suspect this is a bug when multi currency is enabled.